mmenujs (9.3.0) reloading mobile page (iphone firefox/chrome) if menù have more the 500 elements
I have this problem if the ul > li are more then 1000 node, the page go to under infiniti reload ad the browser stop loading for protection
I try to reduce the nodes (300) and work fine.
Do you now if Mmenujs hav a limits of node
Full menu for test
<nav><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Auto & Motorrad (1222)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Anhänger & Trägersysteme (354)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Rampe & Anhängerzubehör (180)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Fahrradträger (137)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Auto-Werkstattausstattung (337)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">KFZ Werkzeuge (151)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Wagenheber (127)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Rangierhilfen (35)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Autoteile (172)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Autobatterien (95)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Autozubehör (146)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">KFZ Spannungswandler (71)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Starthilfe (37)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Motorradbedarf (88)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Versorgerbatterien (61)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Navigation & HiFi (85)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Doppel-DIN-Radios (38)</a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Baby & Kind (104)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Kinderwagen & Autositze (69)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Babyschalen & Kindersitze (37)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Kinderwagen (24)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Babyausstattung (35)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Kindersicherheit (27)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Schutzgitter (25)</a></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Drogerie & Gesundheit (87)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Sanitätshaus & Klinikbedarf (68)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Rollstühle & Gehhilfen (44)</a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Elektroartikel (2551)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Haushaltselektronik (2099)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Küchengeräte (982)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Küchenmaschinen (144)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Kühlboxen (126)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Zubehör für Küchengeräte (77)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Fritteusen (59)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Mixer (54)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Saftpressen (52)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Getreidemühlen (45)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">sonstige Küchenmaschinen (42)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Minibacköfen (39)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Allesschneider (34)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Warmhaltegeräte (34)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Mikrowellen (33)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Fleischwölfe (25)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Pastamaschinen (25)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Haushaltsgeräte (559)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Staubsauger (194)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Industriestaubsauger (125)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Nähmaschinen (85)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Akkuladegeräte (62)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Staubsauger-Zubehör (25)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Elektro-Großgeräte (383)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Kochfelder (181)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Dunstabzugshauben (64)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Backöfen (37)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Kühlschränke (29)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Kaffeezubereitung (100)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Kaffeemühlen (90)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Pflege & Wellnessgeräte (75)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Massagegeräte (24)</a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">HiFi & Audio (246)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">HiFi-Komponenten (123)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Lautsprecher (79)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Radios (45)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Musikinstrumente (37)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Fotografie (55)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Optik (43)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Teleskope (26)</a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Bartschneider & Haarschneider (45)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Drucker & Scanner (27)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Telekommunikation (27)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">TV & Sat (27)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Gaming & Spielen (408)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Spielzeuge (373)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Outdoorspielzeug (177)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Bollerwagen (98)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Schaukeln & Rutschen (23)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Kinderfahrzeuge (109)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Kinderroller (44)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Kinder-Gokart (23)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">LEGO (24)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Gaming Zubehör (24)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Gamingstühle (23)</a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Haus & Garten (9507)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Heimwerken (5643)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Elektrowerkzeuge (2386)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Schleifmaschinen (429)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Kreissägen (357)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Akkuschrauber (232)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Schweißgeräte (213)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Kompressoren (183)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Bohrmaschinen (179)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Seilzüge & Seilwinden (139)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Fräsmaschinen (96)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Schlagschrauber (96)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Stichsägen (76)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Hobelmaschinen (69)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">sonstige Elektrowerkzeuge (48)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Multifunktions-werkzeuge (45)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Säbelsägen (38)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Bandsägen (34)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Tacker & Nagler (34)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Drehmaschinen (29)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Abbruchhammer (28)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Baubedarf (1215)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Werkstatteinrichtung (547)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Absauganlage & Werkstattbedarf (165)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Werkstattwagen (75)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Schraubstöcke (64)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Werkbänke & Arbeitstische (61)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Werkstattregal & Aufbewahrung (46)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Maschinentische (39)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Arbeitsböcke (29)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Maschinenständer (24)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Generatoren & Benzinmotoren (291)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Baustellengeräte (82)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Transportgeräte (80)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Leitern (42)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Armaflex & Dämmstoffe (40)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Treppen (26)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Handwerkzeuge (454)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Werkzeugkoffer (156)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Druckluft-werkzeuge (70)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Zangen (40)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Schrauben-schlüssel (35)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Drehmoment-schlüssel (31)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Schneid-werkzeuge (31)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Steckschlüssel (26)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Werkzeugzubehör (348)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">sonstiges Werkzeugzubehör (85)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Werkzeugakkus (73)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Bohrer & Bits (34)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Sägeblätter (34)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Fräser (31)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Führungsschienen (29)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Schleifmittel (25)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Sanitär & Armaturen (323)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Badarmaturen (85)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Duschköpfe (31)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Sanitärinstallationen (49)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Warmwasserspeicher (34)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Küchenarmaturen (29)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Klimatechnik (226)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Ventilatoren (68)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Badlüfter (57)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Klimaanlagen (42)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Luftreiniger (39)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Heizungen (183)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Elektroheizungen (70)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Dieselpumpe & Heizungszubehör (54)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Außenheizungen (50)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Messtechnik (132)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Baulaser (40)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Messwerkzeuge (30)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Eisenwaren (123)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Briefkästen (51)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Tresore (46)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Erneuerbare Energien (83)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Photovoltaik (80)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Solarmodule (48)</a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Kaminwelt (62)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Kamine & Öfen (24)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Malern & Renovieren (54)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Spritzpistolen & Sprühsysteme (41)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Sicherheitstechnik (26)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Garten (3029)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Gartengeräte (977)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Zubehör für Gartenmaschinen (195)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Zubehör für Gartengeräte (119)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Hochdruckreiniger-Zubehör (61)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Hochdruckreiniger (156)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Rasenmäher (139)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Kettensägen (79)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Laubsauger (66)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Motorsensen (65)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Heckenscheren (63)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Häcksler (47)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Holzspalter (45)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Kehrmaschinen (32)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Gartenpflegesets (31)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Vertikutierer (30)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Motorhacken (26)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Pooltechnik (339)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Poolpumpen (67)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Whirlpools (57)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Poolsauger (40)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Gartenduschen (35)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Swimmingpools (35)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Poolplanen (34)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Poolheizungen (29)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Bewässerung (284)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Gartenpumpen (191)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Gartenschläuche (64)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Gartenmöbel (234)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Gartenliegen (38)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Gartenbänke (34)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Gartenmöbel-Sets (30)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Hängematten (27)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Auflagenboxen (26)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Gartenlauben & Überdachungen (211)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Pavillons (81)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Gartenhäuser (66)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Gewächshäuser (42)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Gartenteich (165)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Teichpumpen (139)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Sonnenschutz (154)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Sonnenschirme (101)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Markisen (27)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Grillen (150)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Grills (89)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Grillzubehör (30)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Zäune & Sichtschutz (127)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Weidezäune (39)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Weidezaungeräte (27)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Gartenwerkzeuge (122)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Schubkarren (40)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Erdbohrer (30)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Gartendeko (95)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Gartenbrunnen (57)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Pflanzzubehör (47)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Gartenbau & Personenleitsystem (38)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Schädlingsbekämpfung (26)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Möbel (485)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Schlafzimmermöbel (177)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Matratzen (133)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Lattenroste (31)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Arbeitszimmer (109)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Bürostühle (90)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Küche (51)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Kinderzimmermöbel (34)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Badezimmer (33)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Wohnzimmer (31)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Haushaltswaren (213)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Töpfe & Pfannen (72)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Töpfe (57)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Küchenutensilien (42)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Mülleimer (40)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Bürobedarf & Schreibwaren (61)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Heimtextilien (29)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Kissen (25)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Dekoration & Saisonartikel (28)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Mode & Accessoires (222)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Taschen & Gepäck (130)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Koffer (53)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Rucksäcke (34)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Uhren (50)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Armbanduhren (49)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Handarbeit (29)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Nähzubehör & Kurzwaren (29)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Schneiderpuppen (27)</a></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Sport & Outdoor (2044)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Camping (749)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Zelte (322)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Campingmöbel (107)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Campingkocher (60)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Camping-Toiletten (54)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Wohnmobil-Zubehör (54)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Dutch Ovens (44)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Campingmatten (36)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Schlafsäcke (30)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Sportartikel (599)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Fitness & Krafttraining (274)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Hanteln (59)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Sportmatten (49)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Trampoline (37)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Klettern (79)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Klettertraining (79)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Wassersport (71)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Stand-Up-Paddling (48)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Skaten (37)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Hoverboards (37)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Wintersport (33)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Wintersport-Zubehör (24)</a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Fahrradwelt (350)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Fahrradzubehör (326)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Fahrradanhänger (238)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Fahrradtaschen (44)</a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Caravaning (212)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Wohnmobil-Markisen (62)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Wohnmobil-Fenster (60)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Wohnmobil-Innenausstattung (44)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Vorzelte (32)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Outdoorausrüstung (109)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Ferngläser (82)</a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Tierbedarf (754)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Aquaristik (210)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Aquarien (67)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Aquarienfilter (53)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Aquarium-beleuchtung (49)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Aquaristik-Zubehör (39)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Katzen (208)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Kratzbäume (120)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Tier-Transportboxen (53)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Vögel (124)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Vogelkäfige & Volieren (52)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Hühnerställe (36)</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Vogelbedarf (32)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Nager (107)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Kaninchenstall & Nagerkäfige  (106)</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Hunde (62)</a><ul><li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Hundezubehör (31)</a></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></nav>

And thi si the js
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    
            const menu = new Mmenu( "#menu", {
                "classNames": {
                    "divider": ""
                },
                "backButton": {
                    "close": false
                },
                "offCanvas": {
                    "position": "left-front",
                    "page": {
                        "selector": ".body-content"
                    }
                },
                "setSelected": {
                  "hover": true,
                  "parent": true
                },
                "navbar": {
                    "title": '<?= _('Categorie'); ?>'
                },
                //"navbars": [{
                //  "position": "bottom",
                //  "content": [
                //  ]
                //}],
                "slidingSubmenus": true,
                "extensions": ["fx-menu-slide"],
                'lazySubmenus': {
                    'load': true
                },
                "extensions": [
                    "position-left"
                ]
            });

        }

    );

HTML to open the menu
<a href="#menu" id="btn-mmenu" data-action="mmenu" class="btn btn-light btn-icon">open</li>
Thenks

I try to set "slidingSubmenus": false and the menù work fine
